# did the git submodule behavior change?

Tags: git-submodules

I am using a new red hat os, with git version 1.7.6 (also tried 1.9.2).  I also have a debian 6 machine with git 1.7.6.  When I create a clone and populate a submodule on the debian machine, the submodule ends up with a .git directory.  However, when I perform the same commands on the red hat machine, my submodule ends up with a file named .git, and a new directory under my root repo in .git, named modules. This modules directory appears to contain the contents I would expect to be in .git under the submodule.  What is going on???

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it did change in git 1.7.8, to make checking out commits across the introduction of submodules easier.

See https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt near the end of the Updates, above the fixes.